# Sandwich covariance for robust regression using M estimators for data exhibiting heteroskedasticity

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, robust

Following the answer and comments on [Python Statsmodels Testing Coefficients from Robust Linear Model based on M-Estimators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21538519/2829605):

I'm wondering how the sandwich form of an m estimator's covariance matrix would be calculated.  The RLM regression will devalue outliers, but my understanding is that it does not control for heteroscedasticity.  I have both systematic outliers and heteroscedasticity in my data and am interested in how to come up with a heteroscedastically controlled covariance matrix for the RLM.

Additional information: using the Huber's t norm at tuning parameter = 1.345 and MAD scaling.

Comment: have you looked into adapting the kNN approach of [Zhao (2000)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3533180)?